# Does "find" in Cypress wait for GraphQL requests to finish?

Tags: graphql, cypress

I am learning to write tests for a MERNQ stack application and I am using cypress as my End to End testing tool. I am trying to make sure that my tests are written correctly so that they work as a long term solution. For now I just have one request for the route in question and I have the following test code:

```
describe('Song API', () => {
    it('should show at least one song', () => {
        cy.server();
        // cy.route('GET', '/graphql').as('graphql');
        cy.route({
            method: 'GET', // Route all GET requests
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql', // that have a URL that matches '/graphql'
            response: {
                data: {
                    loading: false,
                    songs: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            name: 'Boo Ya',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        }).as('getSongs');
        cy.visit('http://localhost:8080').then(() => {
            cy.get('.collection').find('.collection-item');
        });
    });
});
```

I don't understand what about this code makes it wait for the graphql response to finish before running and additionally I am not getting the data that I set but instead the actual data from the database.

This seems very strange to me.

My component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

const SongList = ({ data }) => {
    // console.log(data);
    function renderSongs() {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.loading) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>;
        } else {
            return data.songs.map(song => {
                return (
                    <li key={song.key} className="collection-item">
                        {song.title}
                    </li>
                );
            });
        }
    }

    return <ul className="collection">{renderSongs()}</ul>;
};

const query = gql`
    query getSongs {
        songs {
            key: id
            title
        }
    }
`;

export default graphql(query)(SongList);
```

Any thoughts or remarks?

Comment: I have completely zero experience with GraphQL, but the monthly newsletter of Cypress mentioned this repository: https://github.com/tgriesser/cypress-graphql-mock . Maybe this gives you new insights

Comment: Thank you for the resource I will go through it and see if it woks for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have gotten the stubbed data to respond correctly. My test looks like the following:

```
describe('Song API', () => {
    it('should show at least one song', () => {
        cy.server();
        cy.route('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/graphql', {
            data: {
                songs: [
                    {
                        key: 1,
                        title: 'Hey Ya',
                        __typename: 'SongType',
                    },
                    {
                        key: 2,
                        title: 'Gangsters Paradise',
                        __typename: 'SongType',
                    },
                    {
                        key: 3,
                        title: 'Other Name',
                        __typename: 'SongType',
                    },
                ],
            },
        }).as('getSongs');
        cy.visit('http://localhost:8080')
            .wait('@getSongs')
            .then(() => {
                cy.get('.collection').find('.collection-item');
            });
    });
});
```

I still think there is lots of room for improvement with the ability to get the correct response by the name of the query that is presented.